# How does the server remember logged in users on a password protected website via .htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess, web-hosting

So basically my question is just a technical one.
We password protect our development server so that no duplicated content appears to google if we mirror an existing website.

How does the server remember me, once I logged in with the credentials stored in our .htpasswd file? I guess it has to be a cookie, since in incognito mode, we always get prompted to enter the credentials. But if we look up the cookies set, we don't find anything?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to read on [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). From that article:

> ### Server side
>
> When the server wants the user agent to authenticate itself towards
> the server after receiving an unauthenticated request, it must send a
> response with a HTTP 401 Unauthorized status line[5] and a
> WWW-Authenticate header field.[6]
>
> The WWW-Authenticate header field for basic authentication is
> constructed as following:
>
> ```
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"
> ```
>
> The server may choose to include the charset parameter from RFC
> 7617:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
>
> ```
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm", charset="UTF-8"
> ```
>
> This parameter indicates that the server expects the client to use
> UTF-8 for encoding username and password (see below).
>
> ### Client side
>
> When the user agent wants to send authentication credentials to the
> server, it may use the Authorization header field.
>
> The Authorization header field is constructed as follows:
>
> *The username and password are combined with a single colon (:). This means that the username itself cannot contain a colon.
> The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence. The character set to use for this encoding is by default unspecified, as
> long as it is compatible with US-ASCII, but the server may suggest use
> of UTF-8 by sending the charset parameter.
> The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64 (+/ and with padding).
> The authorization method and a space (e.g. "Basic ") is then prepended to the encoded string.*
>
> For example, if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and open
> sesame as the password, then the field's value is the Base64 encoding
> of Aladdin:open sesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==. Then the
> Authorization header field will appear as:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the server that is remembering you, it is the client.  When you log in with Basic Authentication or Digest Authentication, the browser remembers your login credentials and sends them with each and every request to the server.

Browsers typically remember this information until the browser is restarted and give the web server no control.  It is not usually possible to limit the amount of time that users are logged in, nor to have the web server log them out.

Users that need to log out or log in with different credentials typically have to restart their browser, or use private browsing.  See [How to clear basic authentication details in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome)